# How do I create a bootable ISO image from a running ARM 7 based Debian 9 machine

Tags: debian, clonezilla, syslinux, arch-arm, armbian

I am running a system on a Banana Pi M2+ which I need to clone into a bootable working copy and I cannot find repos for tools like syslinux and clonezilla for the ARM processor.

Is there another solution out there?

Comment: Still think you should have a look grub's document about grub-mkiso and show some efforts in your question.

Comment: How grub-mkiso is supposed to help if OP wants a ARM based Clonezilla?

Comment: Thank you guys, I was not aware that grub-mkiso was available for arm.  I will investigate it and get back to you with my results.  I have been working with Linux-Live-Kit since posting this message and I think I have a solution, but for some reason it is quite slow to boot compared to the original image I installed from.

Comment: Well working with linux-live-kit has been proving to be a waste of time as the ISO images are not bootable.  So I need to find out how to make them bootable for an ARM based architecture.

Answer (score 0):

I would use "dd". The only downside is the final image will be the same size as the HDD. But since it's a pie, i'm guessing it won't be too big.

I'm just copying this answer --> https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/275778/130767

---

Yes there is a way. The machine doesn't even always need to be the same, since Linux creates the `/dev`, `/proc` and `/sys` filesystems on the fly as the kernel boots which gives you a lot of freedom to make some pretty drastic hardware changes.

Let's say your OS is installed on disk `/dev/sda`. You can make an ISO of `/dev/sda` and all of its partitions, whatever they may be, with the following command:

`dd if=/dev/sda of=/path/to/image.iso`

The downside to this is that the image will be the full size of the disk you specified as if (input file), even if that disk is not full.

If you'd like to clone the disk directly from /dev/sda, simply insert another disk and use something like:

`dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb`

Comment: You could look into Qemu to test this image vs using real USB + Terminal, but Qemu was hard to setup and might not work as expected.